# Iterating over an array and joining with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, bluebird

Is there a better way to write this? For the most part, the code below works, but I would like to clean it up if possible.

For reference, `outputs` in the initial callback is an array of objects, containing the file path and some metadata. I would like to have access to this metadata when calling `this.track.attach()`, but I'm unsure how to access it later in the promise chain.

```
var query  = Track.findById('54d5059b7403dda6395bb08b').exec();
var encode = encoder.encode('/* file path */');

Promise.join(query, encode, function (track, outputs) {
  this.track = track;
  return Promise.map(outputs, function (output) {
    return upload.create(output.path, '/jr' + path.extname(output.path));
  });
}).each(function (output) {
  this.track.attach(output.name, 'media');
}).then(function () {
  return this.track.saveAsync();
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
}).finally(function () {
  encoder.cleanup();
}).bind({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one thing you could do. It avoids the hacky `.bind()` and `this.track`:

```
var query  = Track.findById('54d5059b7403dda6395bb08b').exec();
var encode = encoder.encode('/* file path */');

function createForOutput(output) {
    return upload.create(output.path, '/jr' + path.extname(output.path));
}

function saveToOutputs(track, outputs) {
    return Promise.map(outputs, createForOutput)
    .each(function (output) {
        track.attach(output.name, 'media');
        return track.saveAsync();
    });
}

Promise.join(query, encode, saveToOutputs)
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
}).finally(function () {
  encoder.cleanup();
});
```

This approach uses a bit deeper nesting, but I think it may be a little clearer:

```
var query  = Track.findById('54d5059b7403dda6395bb08b').exec();
var encode = encoder.encode('/* file path */');

function createForOutput(output) {
    return upload.create(output.path, '/jr' + path.extname(output.path));
}

function saveToOutputs(track, outputs) {
    return Promise.each(outputs, function (output) {
        createForOutput(output).then(function () {
            track.attach(output.name, 'media');
            return track.saveAsync();
        });
    });
}

Promise.join(query, encode, saveToOutputs)
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
}).finally(function () {
  encoder.cleanup();
});
```

Comment: I would like to improve on this by adding a promise that downloads the file. Do you have any tips on how to handle this case?

I think my main problem is understanding how Promise.join() passes arguments to each function that returns a thenable (or Promise, whatever you call it.). Once I can grasp this, I'll be out of the weeds.

Comment: @NicholasYoung I'm afraid that's a bit too vague. At what point in the process do you want to download the file? Using what as inputs? Is it just one file, or one file for each `output`? Etc., etc.